# How does a while statement in ruby work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby and I noticed something strange. When my nth element reaches 101 it will not go out of the loop even when it says 
`while n < 101`. Can someone explain why this is happening ?

```
n = 0
sum = 0
while n < 101
        n = n +1
        sum = sum + n
        puts "The count is #{n}"
        puts "The sum is #{sum}"
end
puts "The sum is: #{sum}"
```

Comment: btw this is an assignment where I need to find the sum of 0 to 100

Comment: Look at where you've put the `puts "The count is #{n}"`. It's after you add one to the count: `n = n + 1`.

Comment: I'm such a fool ...thanks !!

Comment: Btw you can do `(0..100).sum` to get the sum in Ruby or google Gauss for a more direct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @sagarpandya82 mentioned,

> Look at where you've put the puts "The count is #{n}". It's after you
>   add one to the count: n = n

To answer your original question (i think), in your loop n is 100, then you add 1 to it and reaches 101 and then terminates. That's why your last output is 101.

If you want to do something 100 times, you can also do

```
sum = 0
100.times do |n|
  sum += n
  puts "the count is: #{n + 1}"
  puts "The sum is: #{sum}"
end
```

n starts at `0` and goes to `99` (100 times)

Answer (score 1):

You may be confuse because it prints `count is 101`, that's because you're incrementing the counter before you print.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear…

Slower…

When n reachs 100:

```
 n = 100
```

So:

```
while n < 101 # => while 100 < 101
```

… is true, the loop can go on.

We go on:

```
n = n + 1    # n += 1 should be better
```

So, now:

```
n = 101
```

And we follow:

```
while n < 101 # => while 101 < 101
```

… is `false`.

So we stop with value of n : `101`, not `100`.